# Testing for SVG mask support in JS

Tags: javascript, svg

Is there a way to test for SVG mask support in Javascript? I looked in modernizr, I didn't find anything. I'm using Snap.svg, and I looked at all the attributes in the object before it was added to the dom and it looks the same.

Answer (score 1):

`document.implementation.hasFeature("http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Mask", "1.0")` should do it

Comment: This returns false in chrome... but it works in chrome.

Comment: I sent a bug report to the Chrome devs. I still need a cross browser solution. Is there another way to check?

Comment: "1.1" is recommended to test, works where needed, but returnes a wrong "true" on android 4+

Comment: Raise a bug on the Android bugtracker and either fix it yourself, pay someone to do so or wait till some other Android developer fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most elegant solution, but this worked for me:

```
var browserSupportsSvgMasks = (function () {
    ﻿var el = document.createElement("div");
    var result;

    if (typeof window.getComputedStyle !== "function") {
        // IE8 has no window.getComputedStyle and does not support svg
        return false;
    }

    el.style.visibility = "hidden";
    el.style.position = "absolute";
    el.innerHTML = '<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><rect mask="url()" /></svg>';
    document.body.appendChild(el);
    result = window.getComputedStyle(el.firstChild.firstChild).width === "auto";
    document.body.removeChild(el);
    return result;
})();
```

Feel free to improve and give feedback.